# Unable to build flutter app on vscode using "flutter build apk" command

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I just started learning about flutter.
and i have tried building my first app, that's the flutter demo, each time i create an app, it results to the following error.

Building with sound null safety
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file *****\Desktop\App\appus\android\app\build.gradle' line: 26
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected
> 1, found 0.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           10.2s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Please how do i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by deleting the folder

```
c:\users\[myusername]\.gradle\caches\2.14.1
```

restart your IDE it will be fixed.

Comment: Hey, Sameer! Sorry for the late response. This approach was helpful. It solved the issue. Thanks!!